# What exactly does a selector do in angular 2?

Tags: angular

What does the selector do in this case?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [HighlightDirective]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And what does it do in this case?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave()'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The component is applied to the `<my-app></my-app>` tag in your `index.html`. If your `index.html` doesn't have that tag Angular will fail at startup. You can control where you Angular application will be played.

This is special for the Angular component that is created using `bootstrap(AppComponent)`

The directive selector `[myHighlight]` will create a`MyHighlight` directive instance for all elements that have a `myHighlight` attribute like `<xxx myHighlight>` and where `MyHighLight` is listed in directives like

```
@Component({
  selector: '...', 
  directives: [MyHighlight], ...
})
export class Xxx
```

Like the directive selector for other components (that are not the root component like AppComponent usually is), it works the same like the selector for the directive. The component has to be listed in the `directives` array. Then all tags that match the selector are upgraded to Angular components.

Selectors are like CSS selectors. They can be attribute selectors, tag selectors, class selectors, id selectors and combinations of these. Also `:not(...)` is supported.

What is not supported are selectors that need to match parent and child like with combinators like `a b` or `a > b` or `a + b` where b is a sibling, child, descandant, ... of another component. A directive or component selector can always only refer to a single element.

Comment: I updated my answer. Just post a comment if the explanation is not clear enough.

Answer (score 16):

If we say in simple term selector is name which is used in our view like html tag. as we all know angular2 is component based. so selector is just provide the name of the component which is being called by its className in the directives list and called by selector name in the view of the another component like this:-

//suppose this is our component

```
@Component({
 selector : 'mycomponent'
 ....
})
export class Mycomponent{ }
```

now we can use this component in another component like this -

```
@Component({
 selector : 'secondcomponent',
 directives: [Mycomponent],  //here we use class name instead of selector name
 template: '<mycomponent></mycomponent>'  //here we used selector name
 ....
})
export class Mycomponent{ }
```

Also we can say selector is a complete functionality name used as html tag in the view.

Comment: Hi pradeep,how to send data with this meta tag i.e <mycomponent></mycomponent>

Comment: @MMR try to use `@input` and `@output`

Comment: Ya pradeep i used @input but i am unable to access to it unless I put it in ngOnInit() and i cant access to new value of input since it is in Ngoninit.

Comment: have you declared value of `@input` on the top of constructor ?

Comment: Yes i did,if u need more clarity.I can create  a new question.

Comment: yeah sure anytime @MMR

Comment: Pardeep,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202840/how-to-access-the-values-through-directive-tag-in-angular-2