# How to access the values through directive tag in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

My firsthtml,

```
   <modal [hero]="imageId"></modal>-->
```

My first.component.ts,

```
 export class CommonComponent  {
     photodata:any;
     imageId:any = '2';
 }
```

My model.component.ts,

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'modal',
   templateUrl: './app/modal/modal.component.html',
   providers: [HeaderClass]
 })

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit  {
    @Input() hero: string;
    console.log(hero)--->Undefined
  constructor(){
   console.log(this.hero)---->undefined
 }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.hero)---->2
  }
 }
```

Here when I console it on ngOnInit it shows the value but when I do the same out side of it it says undefined.I am accessing this modal component from firstcomponent but the hero value is unchanged it remains with same value since it is in ngOninit()?.Can any one please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is the problem with "ngOnInit renaming with same value" ?

Comment: @Mozgor,edited my sentense..

Comment: Input parameters are not set in constructor yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#oninit

> Use ngOnInit() for two main reasons:
>
> 1. To perform complex initializations shortly after construction.
> 2. **To set up the component after Angular sets the input properties.**

Comment: I am unable to console this.hero without w=using ngOnInti()?

Comment: Not in the constructor. In `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterContentInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` you can.

Comment: Sorry I missed anything.As u said not in constructor()

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. You access your directive value the right way, but you seem to expect it to be set in the constructor. What you need to understand is, your component is built (aka constructor) and *then* is initialized (including retrieving @Input properties).

Therefore it is the expected behaviour to get `undefined` before `ngOnInit()` got executed. After that, your `hero` variable will be set to the input value.

I might missunderstand your questionning about the value remaining the same, but as long as you don't update your `imageId` variable (and therefore the input), there is no reason your `hero` should be changed.

Comment: I did not put my whole code i.e where I am updating my imageId value dynamically.

Comment: Are you sure your updates are effective ? I mean, are you sure your `imageId:any = '2'` isn't overriding those ?