# What’s the use of "selector" in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to Angular and following the [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) from the official website.

I downloaded the part 5 tutorial, and saw the code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
```

in one of the components. Reading up to the beginning of the tutorial and looking through the documentation, it says that the selector matches the element in your HTML, but when I check all the HTML files in the downloaded example, there's no element with a `<my-heroes></my-heroes>` tag. Still, it works perfectly fine with no error.

What, then, is the purpose of `selector: 'my-heroes'`?

I even tried changing its name to something like

```
selector: 'my-heroes223'
```

and it continued to work without any error or warning.

**Note: This is not duplicate question of any post. My question is that "why does selector not have any effect if its mentioned otherwise in documentations"**

Comment: you can use it as template so you can simply use it <my-heroes223></my-heroes223> as you own html tag in another views

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does a selector do in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091718/what-exactly-does-a-selector-do-in-angular-2)

Comment: you're saying it's working without the error, is component template rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is doing the job for you.

you can inspect `app.component.ts` file. inside `template` they defined `router-outlet`.

Here are the two routes specified in `àpp.component.ts`

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
<a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
```

what it does is when you click on a link `Dashboard or Heroes` it will check for the appropriate `component class` in `app-routing.module.ts` where routes are defined and display the content accordingly.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];
```

Here is a use case for `selector`.

If you want to add a footer to your app first generate a footer component with `Angular cli` like this  `ng generate component footer`. then you can add the footer in `app.component.ts` like this

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Then `footer component` will be common to app and `router-outlet` will take care which component to load.

Comment: can you please explain how will `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` work? Does it display any "selector's" value ?

Answer (score 3):

selector will say what will be a name of tag in parent template. Your component will be inserted to that tag. Using that tag with corresponding selector name you can pass parameters (and do actions off course) to component which owns selector. And catch too (in component).

Answer (score 2):

> selector - defines the name of the HTML tag where the component will
>   live. In this case, your component will by shown through the
>    tags in the DOM.

Reference - [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#metadata)

Comment: If this is a citation from the Angular docs. A link would be great.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i just updated the link , the wordings are tweaked a bit meaning the same

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to use C# dictionary to make analogy for it.
The dictionary in C# has key and value pair. Each key has the corresponding value.

Somehow the selector likes a key in the dictionary, bring the key to the component in the parent html then the corresponding value will be rendered.

Comment: Not related to the question asked